# Why is my web SQL statement executed twice?

Tags: javascript, web-sql

When I try to do any kind of sql (select, insert, ...), my statement gets executed twice.
This is very annoying when my data gets added twice.

```
function createEntry()
{
var myDB = openDatabase("foodentries", "1.0", "Tabel voor eten", 1000000);
myDB.transaction(function (tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY    AUTOINCREMENT, date DATE NOT NULL, calories INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, longitude  TEXT, latitude TEXT)');

    var calorie = $('#calories').val();
    var eten = $('#food').val();
    var dag = sessionStorage.currentDate;
    var latitude = "";
    var longitude = "";

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

    function (position) {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    });

    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO entries (date, calories, name, longitude, latitude) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [dag, calorie, eten, latitude, longitude]);

    //Verwijder de waarden uit de tekstvakken
    $("#calories").val("");
    $("#food").val("");
});
```

}

Has anybody any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What language is this written in?

Comment: How is this being called from the application? Remember that everything in Web SQL is asynchronous.

Comment: $('#Dates li a').bind('click touchend', function () {
        var dayOffset = this.id; //adhv van de ID bepaal je de dag
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() - dayOffset);
        sessionStorage.currentDate = date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
        refreshEntries();
    });